# TQFP-64 to DIL Adapter

Tags: adapter

I was wondering if someone had a link to a board file for a TQFP-64 to DIL-64. Similar to this: http://www.core.st/projects/AVR32_Starter_Kit/TQFP-48_to_DIL-48_adaptor.pdf, but for 64 pins?

Comment: What do you mean by "board file"? And just to clarify, you are not interested in purchasing an existing adapter, is that correct?

Comment: That is correct. I would like to etch the board on my own

Comment: Presumably a "board file" would be a circuit board design in some unspecified package, or else gerbers.  It shouldn't take very long to design your own however... and maybe an hour to fabricate it.  Of course those that you can buy will be stronger, if you have time to wait for them to arrive.

Comment: I need to test this within the next two days, so I believe it would be better to build it myself. I have no experience with designing PCBs

Comment: I'll ask again, what do you mean by a "board file"? Can you use a Gerber file or do you need something like a pdf? Do you need g-code for a milling machine?

Answer (score 1):

Yourself should design the adapter but maybe this link:

http://www.mikrocontroller.net/topic/88269

Or this will help you:

http://www.miklobit.com/Adapters_SMD_DIL.515+B6Jkw9Mw__.0.html

If you don't want to pay money for buy a PCB design program, you can use some free program like freePCB:

http://www.freepcb.com/

I hope this answer help you.